# Installing ADB drivers for Micromax A89 Ninja - Windows 8

Tags: adb, usb-drivers, micromax

Micromax does not provide any drivers for its phone - Micromax A89 Ninja. We are trying to use the phone for development and are unable to install the device driver in Windows 8.

We tried the ADB drivers at  - http://www.droidextra.org/2013/02/06/install-adb-drivers-for-any-android-device.html
and got the error

> Windows found driver software for your device but encountered an error when trying to install it. Android ADB Interface - The system cannot find the file specified.

We even tried this link - https://laslow.net/2012/03/14/disable-driver-signature-enforcement-in-windows-8/

But that does not solve the problem. How do we install ADB driver for Micromax A89? Is there any other workaround to use the phone as a development device?

Comment: Have you tried [this guide](http://www.droidiser.com/2012/11/how-to-install-drivers-for-any-android.html)? If still fails, try the same on Windows XP (either virtual or real).

Answer (score -1):

Please try official one - works for most devices:
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html

Comment: AFAIK, if you meant "[Google USB Driver](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb)", then it only works for Google devices. For other devices, users need to install respective [USB driver for their device](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb) (though no source for Micromax).